# Save object within an array from api response

Tags: php, laravel, linkedin-api

I'm making a call to LinkedIn's API using socialite in laravel and get the following response:

```
Laravel\Socialite\Two\User Object
(
[token] => 
[refreshToken] => 
[expiresIn] => 
[id] => 
[nickname] => 
[name] => 
[email] => l
[avatar] => 
[user] => Array
    (
        [emailAddress] => 
        [firstName] =>
        [formattedName] =>
        [headline] =>
        [id] =>
        [industry] =>
        [lastName] =>
        [location] => Array
            (
                [country] =>
                    (
                        [code] =>
                    )
                [name] =>
            )
        [pictureUrl] =>
        [positions] => Array
            (
                [_total] => 1
                [values] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [company] => Array
                                    (
                                        [name] =>
                                    )
                                [id] =>
                                [isCurrent] =>
                                [location] => Array
                                    (
                                        [country] => Array
                                            (
                                                [code] =>
                                                [name] =>
                                            )
                                        [name] =>
                                    )
                                [startDate] => Array
                                    (
                                        [month] =>
                                        [year] =>
                                    )
                                [summary] => 
                                [title] => 
                            )
                    )
            )

        [publicProfileUrl] =>
        [summary] =>
[avatar_original] => 
)
```

I'm then saving the responses to my database but can't work out how to properly access the values for positions, publicProfileUrl or summary. All others work out of the box with socialite with the following:

```
        $user = User::where('provider_id', $linkedin_user->id)->first();

    if (!$user){
      $user = new User;
      $user->name = $linkedin_user->getName();
      $user->email = $linkedin_user->getEmail();
      $user->picture = $linkedin_user->getAvatar();
      $user->provider_id = $linkedin_user->getId();
      $user->access_token = $linkedin_user->token;
      $user->save();
    }
```

I've tried adding this:

```
$publicProfileUrl = array_get($linkedin_user, 'user.publicProfileUrl', null);
```

After this:

```
$user = User::where('provider_id', $linkedin_user->id)->first();
```

And adding this before saving the user:

```
$user->linkedin = $linkedin_user[user]->publicProfileUrl;
```

But am stumped!

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AbstractUser` which is a parent of `Two\User` has a `getRaw` method (https://github.com/laravel/socialite/blob/3.0/src/AbstractUser.php#L106), which will return you simple array:

```
$user = $linkedin_user->getRaw();
echo $user['publicProfileUrl'];
print_r($user['positions']);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response -

Comment: If answer helps - feel free to __accept__ it. It will raise your repo and help other SO visitors.

Comment: I'm struggling to implement this - I'm wanting to create a new User and save the publicProfileUrl where $user->linkedin = ...........how would I write this?

Comment: `= $linkedin_user->getRaw()['publicProfileUrl']`?

Comment: HERO. Thank you! Answer accepted. What about if I want to get to company name value which is buried within positions. How would you access this given that there are two multiple values stored as 'name'?